# Application exit when CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync in Azure cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Im trying using Azure cosmos db.

when calling CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync function the application is exit without any exception or message.

```
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);
var database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId);
```

The cosmosClient creation succeeded, which means the credentials are correct

Comment: Are you perhaps using this in a console app? Remember that you need to use `static async Task Main()` to wait for the async operation to complete.

Comment: I have the same problem. In .net 7 it crashed, but in .net 8 it just hangs. I was trying to trace it and the method is running fine, but the "await/task" code in .net doesn't return to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

> The cosmosClient creation succeeded, which means the credentials are correct

That is not true. When you create the client, there is no validation done of the credential's correctness (only the format).

If the application is exiting it means either that you have an unhandled exception, in which case you need to add a try/catch block. Or simply control is falling through.

Can you share how is the code called? Is you application code just running those 2 lines or is there more? How are the `async` methods called? Could you be calling some `async` method without `await`? For example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2961